# Intellij local setup war file dependency

Tags: intellij-idea, war

I'm trying to do a local setup to trace a call that starts at a jar file (front end) and uses the base code given in a separate war file. In Intellij is there a way to setup this scenario locally?
What I got so far is to have a tomcat run config for the jar file code and use "before launch" setting in it to try different options to deploy the war file. But this seems like a approach that wouldn't work so wanted to see anyone has faced a similar issue before.

Answer (score 0):

In the Server Tab of Run/Debug Edit configurations,  you can manually configure the Tomcat server with the "Add New Configuration" option. Configure the tomcat install location directory for Catalina Home & Catalina Base
For URL, enter eg: "http://localhost:8080/ui/".

- Use "update Classes and Resources" for "On Update action" and "On
  frame deactivation" options.
- Now, In "Deployment tab" section-> click
  on the + symbol to add Artifacts such as the following  Select "your war
  file", click OK, and enter the suitable Application Context as
  "/ui/test"
- Select "another war file", click OK, and enter suitably
  Application Context as "/ui/api"
- Enter any name for Tomcat configuration.
- In the "Before Launch" section at the bottom of the
  "Server" tab, click on the + symbol from the list of tasks in the
  "Add New Task" popup, and select "Run Gradle task" or "maven",
  depending upon what you have.
- In the "Select Gradle task" window,

  - Click on the folder icon next to the Gradle Project text box and
    choose "war" project
  - Click on OK Check that the selected Run Gradle task is shown in the
    Before Launch window.
  - check the order and "Build 2 artifacts". Click Apply.